# Why am I getting this error? - "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

I wrote below batch script. I am not able to figure out why it is throwing *The syntax of the command is incorrect.*

```
@echo off    
:: ============================================================================
::  Windows batch script to take a .zip backup of configured directories
:: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
call :getDateTimeISO8601 ISO8601_DateTime
SET EXECUTION_START_TIME=%ISO8601_DateTime:~0,13%.%ISO8601_DateTime:~14,2%.%ISO8601_DateTime:~17,2%

SET LOG_FILE=%~n0 [%EXECUTION_START_TIME%].log

:: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::  Configure backup directory and associated backup locations here
:: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET BACK_UP_DIRS[1].SourceDir="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Received Files"
SET BACK_UP_DIRS[1].BackupLocation=".\backup"
SET BACK_UP_DIRS[2].SourceDir="%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
SET BACK_UP_DIRS[2].BackupLocation=".\backup"

SET MAIL_NOTIFICATION_TO=nitesh@bbd.co.za
SET MAIL_SUBJECT=Backup Script Execution Report From %COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME% at %EXECUTION_START_TIME%
SET MAIL_SIGNATURE=^<b^>^<br/^>Thanks,^<br/^> Test Automation Team.^</b^>


:: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: -- Executable Code                           [Note: Don't touch below here]
:: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    call :log Execution started at %EXECUTION_START_TIME%
    SET MailMessageHTML=^<p^>Hi,^</p^>
    SET MailMessageHTML=!MailMessageHTML!^<p^>The backup script execution summary from %COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME% is below. Please find the detailed log attached.^</p^>
    SET MailMessageHTML=!MailMessageHTML!^<ul^>

    SET SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0

    call :len BACK_UP_DIRS length

    for /l %%i in (1,1,%length%) do (
        call :log Processing... %%i of %length%
        if defined BACK_UP_DIRS[%%i] do (
            call :absolute_path_from_relative !BACK_UP_DIRS[%%i].SourceDir! sourceDir
            call :absolute_path_from_relative !BACK_UP_DIRS[%%i].BackupLocation! backupLocation
            call :get_name_only "!sourceDir!" sourceDirName

            set backupZipFile=!backupLocation!\!sourceDirName! [!EXECUTION_START_TIME!].zip

            ::call :runZip "!sourceDir!" "!backupZipFile!" 1>>"%LOG_FILE%"

            SET MailMessageHTML=!MailMessageHTML!^<li^>[%date% %time%] The directory '^<em^>!sourceDir!^</em^>' is backed up as '^<em^>!backupZipFile!^</em^>'.^</li^>

        )
    )
    SET MailMessageHTML=!MailMessageHTML!^</ul^>

    cd %SCRIPT_DIR%
    SET BACK_UP_DIRS=
    call :log Execution completed at %date% %time%

    ::call :sendEmail "!MailMessageHTML!"
    del "%LOG_FILE%"
endlocal
goto :EOF

::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts here
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:len <inputArrayName> <outputLength>
SETLOCAL
    set arrayName=%1
    set arrayIndex=0
    for /f "delims=[=] tokens=2" %%a in ('set %arrayName%[') do (
        set arrayIndex=%%a
    )
( ENDLOCAL
    SET "%~2=%arrayIndex%"
)
goto :EOF

:absolute_path_from_relative <inputRelativePath> <outputAbsolutePath>
SETLOCAL
    set absolutePath=%~f1
( ENDLOCAL 
    set "%~2=%absolutePath%"
)
goto :EOF

:get_directory_path <inputFilePath> <outputDirectoryPath>
SETLOCAL
    set dirPath=%~dp1
( ENDLOCAL
    set %~2=%dirPath%
)
goto :EOF

:get_name_only <inputPath> <outputName>
SETLOCAL
    set name=%~nx1
( ENDLOCAL
    set %~2=%name%
)
goto :EOF

:runZip <sourceDir> <backupZipFile>
SETLOCAL
    call :log Taking backup of '%~1' to '%~2'
    if not exist "%~dp2" mkdir "%~dp2"
    cd /d "%~1"
    call %ZIP_EXE% -dcR9 "%~2" *
    cd /d %~dp0
    call :log Completed backup of '%~1' to '%~2'
    echo.
ENDLOCAL
goto :EOF

:sendEmail <message>
SETLOCAL
    echo Sending Email..
    ::echo Message: %~1
    call %BLAT_EXE% -server %SMTP_MAIL_SERVER% -port %SMTP_PORT% -f %MAIL_SENDER% -from %MAIL_SENDER% -to %MAIL_NOTIFICATION_TO% -html -subject "%MAIL_SUBJECT%" -body "%~1 %MAIL_SIGNATURE%" -attach "%LOG_FILE%"
    echo Email Sent.
ENDLOCAL
goto :EOF

:getDateTimeISO8601 <outputValue>
SETLOCAL
    :: Check WMIC is available
    WMIC.EXE Alias /? >NUL 2>&1 || GOTO :no_wmic

    :: Use WMIC to retrieve date and time
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
       IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
          SET _yyyy=%%L
          SET _mm=00%%J
          SET _dd=00%%G
          SET _hour=00%%H
          SET _minute=00%%I
          SET _second=00%%K
    )
    :s_done

    :: Pad digits with leading zeros
          SET _mm=%_mm:~-2%
          SET _dd=%_dd:~-2%
          SET _hour=%_hour:~-2%
          SET _minute=%_minute:~-2%
          SET _second=%_second:~-2%

    :: Display the date/time in ISO 8601 format:
    SET _isodate=%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dd% %_hour%:%_minute%:%_second%
    goto :functionDone

    :no_wmic
    echo WMIC not available on this machine.
    Set _isodate=%date% %time%
    :functionDone
( ENDLOCAL
    SET "%~1=%_isodate%"
)
goto :EOF

:log <message>
SETLOCAL
    set message=%~n0 [%date% %time%] %*
    if "%LOG_FILE%"=="" goto :console
        echo %message% >> "%LOG_FILE%"
    :console
    echo %message%
ENDLOCAL
goto :EOF
```

I am getting error at the end of function `len` when cmd is processing `goto :EOF`.

```
:len <inputArrayName> <outputLength>
SETLOCAL
    set arrayName=%1
    set arrayIndex=0
    for /f "delims=[=] tokens=2" %%a in ('set %arrayName%[') do (
        set arrayIndex=%%a
    )
( ENDLOCAL
    SET "%~2=%arrayIndex%"
)
goto :EOF
```

Can you please help me figure out, what is going wrong here.

```
D:\Work\shell-scripts\shell-scripts>goto :EOF
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - `goto :EOF` is not only correct; it's the preferred method of doing so (other than `exit /b`, of course).

Comment: not enough .bat those days? or is that for the better? sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the way you commented out `call :runzip`.

`::` is technically a label, and batch doesn't allow you to have labels inside of code blocks (`if` statements, `for` loops, and anything else inside of parentheses). To get around this, use `REM` to comment out lines in these situations.

```
REM call :runZip "!sourceDir!" "!backupZipFile!" 1>>"%LOG_FILE%"
```